# Castle Windsor WithService usage

Tags: castle-windsor

I don't understand the meaning of the **WithService** cluster.

What does this line do? Do I need it?

```
container.Register(FromAssembly...Where...WithService...);
```

I found [this document](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx). It has mentioned WithService and WithServiceBase, but not the base meaning of the function.

Comment: Perhaps this primer on terminology will help: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Services-and-Components.ashx

Comment: Yes, very helpful. Didn't understand what that doc was refering to when I first learnt DI. Now I know. Thanks for connecting the dots!